# How to load large amount of data from MySQL and save as text file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm fetching large amount of data from MySql Database using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` like:

```
var offset = 0
for (s <- a to partition) {

  val query = "(select * from destination LIMIT 100000 OFFSET " + offset + ") as src"
  data = data.union(spark.read.jdbc(url, query, connectionProperties).rdd.map(_.mkString(","))).persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)
  offset += 100000
}
val dest = data.collect.toArray
val s = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(dest, 1).persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY).saveAsTextFile("/home/hduser/Desktop/testing")
```

For small amount of data its working fine whereas for large amount of data it throws error like `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` so if i can persist `val dest = data.collect.toArray` it will work as expected, sorry for such a naive question i'm new to spark.

Partition method:

```
val query = "(select * from destination) as dest"
val options = Map(
"url" -> "jdbc:mysql://192.168.175.35:3306/sample?useSSL=false",
"dbtable" -> query,
"user" -> "root",
"password" -> "root")

val destination = spark.read.options(options).jdbc(options("url"), options("dbtable"), "0", 1, 5, 4, new java.util.Properties()).rdd.map(_.mkString(","))
.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY).saveAsTextFile("/home/hduser/Desktop/testing")
```

Thank you

Comment: why are you working like this? why the limit and offset? You are basically losing everything spark gives you and doing the parallelism yourself (and not that well because you move everything to the driver). Can you explain your original goal?

Comment: I'm running it in a standalone machine it throws error if the data exceeds memory so I'm using persist method to store that in Disk

Comment: @AssafMendelson, Table comparison between source and destination, to find mismatch, extra in source and extra in destination using a primary key, source and destination will reside in different databases in remote, if I try to read that in memory it throws GC memory exception that is why I'm persisting it in DISK_ONLY

Comment: I'd suggest to use sqoop if that's what you're gonna do. I don't see any complicated transformations in here, so sqoop should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm fetching large amount of data

That's why you use Spark, *isn't it?* :)

```
 for (s <- a to partition)    
 val dest = data.collect.toArray    
 spark.sparkContext.parallelize(dest, 1)
```

> ***NOTE :*** Don't do that. I'd even call it a Spark anti-pattern where you load a
>   dataset on executors (from MySQL using JDBC) only to transfer this
>   "large amount of data" to the driver that in turn will transfer it
>   back to the executors to save it to disk.

It's as if you wanted to get rid of Spark doing these network round trips.

`spark.read.jdbc` supports partitioning your dataset at load time out of the box using `partitionColumn`, `lowerBound`, `upperBound` options (see [JDBC To Other Databases](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases)) or (undocumented) `predicates` option.

> **partitionColumn**, **lowerBound**, **upperBound** describe how to partition the table when reading in parallel from multiple workers. partitionColumn must be a numeric column from the table in question. Notice that lowerBound and upperBound are just used to decide the partition stride, not for filtering the rows in table. So all rows in the table will be partitioned and returned. This option applies only to reading.

Let Spark do its job(s).

Comment: Please don't. You're making things worse. Show what you tried initially and let's fix it (instead of re-writing Spark where it does its work fairly well).

Comment: I have tried it but no luck its throwing memory error.

Comment: Partition method throws this error `Error sending message [message = Heartbeat(driver,[Lscala.Tuple2;@ab980b,BlockManagerId(drive‌​r, 192.168.175.160, 35635, None))]`

Comment: You have to use the aforementioned options as I described in https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-sql-DataFrameReader.html#jdbc

Comment: Got this error I followed as you suggested `fetchsize, upperbound, lowerbound, number of partition` got this error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`

Comment: How do you `spark-submit` your application? What are the command-line options?

Comment: I'm running it from eclipse, even if I convert it to jar its throws the same memory error `spark-submit --jars /home/hduser/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe/config/bundles/config-1.3.1.jar --class "retail.stack" --master yarn sample-spark-180417_2.11-1.0.jar /input_files`

Comment: Thanks for the book which you wrote, its great..!

Comment: I'm using a standslone  machine of 8GB memory with 4 cores it can capable of fetching 100,000 row at a time even if I use partitions `val destination = spark.read.options(options).jdbc(options("url"), options("dbtable"), "EMPLOYEE_ID", 1, 22, 21, new java.util.Properties())`, thats why I used like above. fetching and storing it to DISK.